# Integrate stylelint with angular build and make it failed on error?

Tags: angular, tslint, stylelint

I want to use `stylelint` in angular application to enforce class name for example (they should be in lowercase and dash if if necessary, not camel case or uppercase).

How to configure `stylelint` to run in Angular build time (just like Angular run TSLint). Or can TSLint enforce style rules?

The propose is when I have an error in `stylelint` rule then Angular build will fail.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of stylelint you can use [selector-class-pattern](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern) with the kebab-case pattern `^([a-z][a-z]*)(-[a-z]+)*$`. This pattern allows only lower case letters and dashes between those letters. If you want to allow also digits you can use this one `^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*$` with every alphanumeric group starting with a letter.

You can also have a look at [resolveNestedSelectors](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern#resolvenestedselectors-true-false-default-false) option of `selector-class-pattern` if you need it.

You can use it in your `stylelint-config.json` file somehow like [this](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/stylelint-config.json),

```
"selector-class-pattern": ["^([a-z][a-z]*)(-[a-z]+)*$", {
   "resolveNestedSelectors": false
}
```

or just,

```
"selector-class-pattern": "^([a-z][a-z]*)(-[a-z]+)*$"
```

I hope it helped :)

EDIT: According to this [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/super-charging-an-angular-cli-app-fc496a6c100), for integrating with angular build, in your package.json you can make your scripts look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "npm run lint && ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint \"apps/**/*.scss\" && stylelint \"libs/**/*.scss\"",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: But how I integrate angular with stylelint in build time? not but run npm command

Comment: @JonSud I edited my answer, can you check now if it helps you?

Comment: No, because I have to run `npm run lint` and `npm start` in parallels. if the lint will have error, then angular doesn't know about this error. I want to check style lint in the build time, in the serve time.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a command for linting [ng lint](https://angular.io/cli/lint).

There is a third party CLI builder available to integrate both ESLint and stylelint. You can then just run ng lint and it will lint with ESLint and stylelint.

https://github.com/krema/angular-eslint-stylelint-builder

PS: I am the author of this package.